# Updating information in SQL via C# Visual Studio does not work

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have created a program (for school) that has create account, manage account (update and delete), and delete account. All functions work except for Update and I am not sure why. There's no error whatsoever, it just does nothing. Below is the code:

```
    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myCon"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Inventory SET ItemID=@ItemID, ItemName=@ItemName, ItemType=@ItemType, Quantity=@Quantity,WarehouseLocation=@WarehouseLocation,QuadrantNumber=@QuadrantNumber,BinNumber=@BinNumber,DateUpdated=@DateUpdated" +
                " WHERE ItemID= '" + txtItemID.Text + "'", con))
        {
            if (txtItemID.Text == "@ItemID")
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemName", txtItemName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemType", cmbType.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", udQuantity.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WarehouseLocation", cmbWarehouse.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuadrantNumber", cmbQuadrant.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BinNumber", cmbBin.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateUpdated", Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now));
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                MessageBox.Show("Item Updated!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why didn't you also parameterize `ItemID` in your `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Update only works if the Primary key already exists in the database.  the instruction cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); returns an integer which indicates the number of rows in the database that changed. If you get zero then it indicates the primary key is not in the database and you need to use Insert.

Comment: `if(txtItemID.Text == "@ItemID")` looks incorrect. I'd expect the @ItemID to be parameterized in the query, and the value of txtItemID.Text to be a command parameter.

Comment: the expression `txtItemID.Text == "@ItemID"` seems odd, out of place. you probably meant to have an @itemID parameter, and the value in the textbox is the actual id?

Comment: Do you have a primary key in `Inventory` table?

Comment: Hi, how do I parameterize? Sorry, I am still starting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based in assumption you already have this item in your DB and you just need to update it. I'll separate the answer in three steps:

**First step:** I assume your **primary_key** is the ItemID, so you shouldn't really update it as you're doing here:

> UPDATE Inventory SET ItemID=@ItemID,...

You should just remove the *ItemID = @ItemID,* part, as we don't want to update it.

**Second step:** Now, this piece of code looks incorrect:

```
if (txtItemID.Text == "@ItemID")
```

It will try to match the txtItemID.Text with the string "@ItemID", which I believe it is not your goal, since I can understand it is your ID - It would be always false.

You should just remove this **if**.

**Third step:** You also need to change your **where** clause to have your ItemID as parameter, as below:

```
" WHERE ItemID=@ItemID", con))
```

Then add it to your parameters:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemID", txtItemID.Text);
```

You should be good with these changes.

Another thing you could do is to always debug your application when you're struggling to understand a problem. It helps a lot!